# backbone.LocalStorage with RequireJS

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, require

Im trying to get up and running with backbone localStorage via the install below

https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage

but I can't figure out how to actually integrate it into my application.  I have connected the collection I want to be stored locally (`saved`) but Im unsure about how to save/fetch models (upon reload).

```
(function($){

        require.config({
            paths: {
                jquery: "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js",
                underscore: "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.7.0/underscore-min.js",
                backbone: "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.1.2/backbone-min.js",
                localStorage: "backbone.localStorage.js"
            }
        });

        define('saved', ['localstorage'], function(){
            var saved = Backbone.Collection.extend({
                localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage('saved')
            });

            return saved;
        });

        //---------SINGLE ENTRY MODEL----------
                var Entry = Backbone.Model.extend({
                    defaults: function(){
                        return{
                            word: '',
                            definition: ''
                        }
                    }
                });

        //------------ENTRY MODEL COLLECTION------------
        EntryList = Backbone.Collection.extend({

                localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage('saved'),

                model: Entry
            });

        //-----INSTANCIATE COLLECTION----
        var dictionary = new EntryList();
        var saved = new EntryList();
        .
        .
        .
```

Answer (score 0):

actually you had already using the localStorage when you do something like this:

```
//------------ENTRY MODEL COLLECTION------------
EntryList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage('saved'),
    model: Entry
});
```

you're initiating variables `dictionary` and `saved` from the same collection, i guess you only want the `saved` to be localStorage? if it is, then it would not be what you expected.
It is because when you add the `localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage('saved')` property while extending the Backbone.Collection, this collection will be forever using the localStorage.

to use it to save, you just have to call `saved.create({ word: 'abc', definition: 'i dun know'})`
to fetch the saved entry, simply `saved.fetch()`

the [example](https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage/blob/master/examples/todos/todos.js) in the source gives a good view

by the way, you can always type "localStorage" to check if it is initiated or having any data on the browser console (i;m using Chrome Devtool)